# Error while trying to run phoenix server

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework

**I keep getting this error whenever i try to run the phoenix server with mix phx.server.**

[error] #PID<0.446.0> running Citybuilder.Web.Endpoint terminated
Server: 0.0.0.0:8080 (http)
Request: GET /
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42P01 (undefined_table): relation "stories_topics" does not exist
        (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:436: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute_and_cache/7
        (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:130: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
        (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:35: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/4
        (citybuilder) lib/citybuilder/web/controllers/post_controller.ex:148: Citybuilder.Web.PostController.set_topics/2
        (citybuilder) lib/citybuilder/web/controllers/post_controller.ex:1: Citybuilder.Web.PostController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (citybuilder) lib/citybuilder/web/endpoint.ex:1: Citybuilder.Web.Endpoint.instrument/4
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:277: Phoenix.Router.**call**/1
        (citybuilder) lib/citybuilder/web/endpoint.ex:1: Citybuilder.Web.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (citybuilder) lib/plug/debugger.ex:123: Citybuilder.Web.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (citybuilder) lib/citybuilder/web/endpoint.ex:1: Citybuilder.Web.Endpoint.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
        (cowboy) /home/saikiran/Documents/citybuilder/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4

**Any help on how to resolve this would be appreciated, Thanks**

Comment: Have you run the database migrations? The error says it could not find the table `stories_topics` in the database.

Comment: I ran these commands in order but no luck : mix ecto.drop
mix ecto.create
mix ecto.migrate

Comment: Actually the migration file was messed up. We corrected and it's working now. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: try logging into your postgres manualy and check if the table/database is there... if yes, drop them and recreate the database then try to run mix ecto.create && mix ecto.migrate